# Why can't I access globals in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to set up a AWS Lambda function and as always, I am keeping my constants in global variables. But for some reason, I am getting the error shown below. I do this all the time and never have issues. I've typed this myself and retyped it a bunch of times so no weird unicode characters. I think I'm going crazy.

[image: Magical Lambda error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you set `b = False` in the same function. By setting it in the function it redefines the variable as a local variable rather than a global variable.

To use it like this you need to define b as a global variable such as

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global b
    print(b[0])
    b = False
```

Comment: Argh! I know global works, but I didn't realise `b = False` would redefine it for the whole method. But now that I actually think about it it makes perfect sense from the compiler's point of view!

Comment: Glad this helped :)

Comment: Maybe this is just test code and it doesn't matter but I highly recommend that you don't redefine `b` from list to boolean in this fashion in real code. Also, note this will impact the next warm invocation of your Lambda function and cause it to fail.